# PreventDefault not working for dynamic link

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<a href="#" class="submit-form show-field" data-show-field="#Product" >View products</a>
```

This link is dynamically added to the dom, and I fire a jQuery function on click

```
$('body').on("click", 'a.show-field', function(e) {
    if (!$(this).attr('data-show-field')) { 
        return; 
    }
    $($(this).attr('data-show-field')).parent().show();
    e.preventDefault();    
});
```

The event fires fine, but page redirects. I cant understand what I've done wrong

Comment: Make `e.preventDefault()` as first line of your function as `return` will not execute `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: Do you get any error in the console?

Comment: Your link goes to `#`, which means that if it performs any action it will be handled by an attached event handler. Because of this `e.preventDefault()` will do nothing in this scenario. You need to find that other attached event handler and amend or remove it.

Comment: Thanks, Ill investigate further and look for other events attached to the link

Comment: This was bound to another event earlier on that had a redirect in the callback - thanks for the help all

Answer (score 0):

You event is fired before you can prevent it.

```
$('body').on("click", 'a.show-field', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();  

    if (!$(this).attr('data-show-field')) { 
        return; 
    }
    $($(this).attr('data-show-field')).parent().show();  
    /*e.preventDefault();  */
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the page redirects then I think your listener is not working well.
Here you are a plunker with a use case.
[With and whithout document ready](https://plnkr.co/edit/yupkE7tgAQnwsSdX48Et)

I don´t know where you put your code, but if it's outside the "document ready" that listener never fires.

```
$('body').on("click", 'a.show-field', function(e) {
  alert("First attemp is attached");
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').on("click", 'a.show-field', function(e) {
    alert("Second attemp is attached");

    if (!$(this).attr('data-show-field')) {
      return;
    }

    $($(this).attr('data-show-field')).parent().show();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

PD: sorry for my english